# PHP 5.3.8 Wordpress CURL Intermittent Error

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, iis-7.5, fastcgi

I upgraded my IIS 7.5 web server to PHP 5.3.8 from PHP 5.2.17.
After doing so, my Wordpress install started intermittently producing 500 errors:

> **HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly**
>
> **Detailed Error Information**
>
> Module **FastCGIModule**
> Notification **ExecuteRequestHandler**
> Handler **PHP53_via_FastCGI**
> Error Code **0x000000ff**

I also run Drupal and the Zend Framework on this server, both of which use CURL, but these did not produce the error. As such, I'd say it's something specific to the Wordpress implementation of CURL.

I looked in the Windows application error log and found the following errors:

> Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.3.8.0, time stamp: 0x4e537f4b
> Faulting module name: php_curl.dll, version: 5.3.8.0, time stamp: 0x4e537f64
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
> Fault offset: 0x00036864
> Faulting process id: 0x378
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cccf17892cff0e
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_curl.dll
> Report Id: ec31f1ab-3b0a-11e1-9d5f-005056b30014

Comment: You should post that second bit as the answer.

Comment: Because I'm new to Stack Overflow I couldn't for 7 hours. Done now. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a manifestation of the following PHP bug, introduced in 5.3.7 with a new version of cURL:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60576

If you don't need the new features from the the new cURL version (such as reading certificates from a file specified in php.ini), download the relevant PHP 5.3.6 Zip file from http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/ and replace ext\php_curl.dll with the PHP 5.3.6 version.

If you do need these features... that's an open question.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I am also experiencing the same problem. My configuration is given below.

> Windows 7
>  Wordpress 3.9.1 (Turkish)
>  Apache 2.4.9 x86 VC11
>   (Windows Lounge binaries)
>  PHP 5.5.14 ts x86 VC11

I am using proxy. Moreover, my proxy requires authentication. I found that one of the request methods in the file `wp-includes/class-http.php` is problematic.

I solved the issue by replacing below lines (line number is 1247)

```
    if ( $proxy->is_enabled() && $proxy->send_through_proxy( $url ) ) {

        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy->host() );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy->port() );

        if ( $proxy->use_authentication() ) {
            curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY );
            curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy->authentication() );
        }

    }
```

with the lines given below.

```
    if ( $proxy->is_enabled() && $proxy->send_through_proxy( $url ) ) {

        $isPHP5 = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '>=');

        if ($isPHP5) {
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy->host());
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy->port());
        } else {
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy->host() . ':' . $proxy->port());
        }

        if ($proxy->use_authentication()) {
            if ($isPHP5)
                curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy->authentication());
        }

    }
```